# внесение метода в Update С#

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

напечатал код для атаки врага и для бега его в пассивное состояние. Бег работает, агрессия работает, но пробовал выключать агрессию для пассивного состояния и также из пассивного в агрессию. Не получилось ибо враг вообще перестал двигаться помогите мне вникнуть в суть написания переключения кода с одного на другой. Вот код из которого я хочу сделать переключение.

```
public Transform start;
public Transform end;

private SpriteRenderer sprite;

public float arriveTime = 3f;

GameObject player;

const float speedMove = 3.5f;


void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}


void Awake() {
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren <SpriteRenderer> ();
}

void Update()
{
        float direction = player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
        sprite.flipX = direction < 0.0f;

        if (Mathf.Abs (direction) < 10) {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            pos.x += Mathf.Sign (direction) * speedMove * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = pos;
    }
}


void Run() {
    Vector3 direction = transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(start.position, end.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time/arriveTime, 1f));
    sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/StateMachineBasics.html

Comment: Ну честно скажу суть вы не поняли. Мне не нужна анимация врага, ведь она лишь одна и это тот же бег, мне нужно внести метод `Run` в `Update` и переключать агрессию и пассивное состояние.